# How do I update ESXi 6.5 patch using ESXCLI in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vmware, esxi

Trying to update ESXi 6.5 Patch using ESXiCLI within powershell.  My path is pointing to a subfolder in datastore called MasterImages.

This is the the path name

- /vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip

Commands being executed:

```
$argsInstall = $esxcli.software.profile.update.createargs()
$argsInstall.depot = $patchfilepath
$esxcli.software.vib.update.Invoke($argsInstall)
```

Below is the error received:

```
Message: EsxCLI.CLIFault.summary;
InnerText:  [MetadataDownloadError] Could not download from depot at
zip:/vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip?index.xml, skipping
(('zip:/vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip?index.xml', '', "Error extracting index.xml from
/vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip'"))        url =
zip:/vmfs/volumes/MasterImages/Patches/ESXi650-20210704001/ESXi650-20210704001.zip?index.xml Please refer to the log file for more
details.EsxCLI.CLIFault.summary
At line:176 char:5
+     $esxcli.software.vib.update.Invoke($argsInstall)}
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], MethodFault
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Types.V1.ErrorHandling.VimException.MethodFault
```

I was able to make an ESX7.0.1 update using `$esxcli.software.vib.update.Invoke($argsInstall)` but with 6.5 this also returns an **error** "*not able to download from depot*".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the absolute path to the zipped file, please use the datastore UUID instead of the name

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2015834